# How do i get my hibernate program to return objects of two classes via HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm new to hibernate and i'm stuck with this join query which just returning a correct answer when asked to return just DeptDataDTO object but when i use the iterator to get two objects one od DeptDataDTo and other of EmpDataDTO i get this errror :

> DeptDataDTO cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

```
List list1 =
            ormHqlWrapper.executeHQLQuery("select  distinct d,e from dept d inner join        fetch d.empData e where d.deptNo=11001640");
       Iterator i = list1.iterator();
       while (i.hasNext()) 
         {
          Object[] ob =(Object[])i.next();
          DeptDataDTO dept1=(DeptDataDTO)ob[0];
           EmpDataDTO emp1 = (EmpDataDTO)ob[1];
         }
```

can anyone please help me out it's an important assignment that i have to complete.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is only returning instances of DeptDataDTO - as a result your cast to Object[] won't work. Try modifying your query, perhaps using a debugger to inspect what your result list actually contains.